# extending a 40TB xfs formated FS over LVM

Tags: lvm, xfs

I need to increase space on my data `volgroup` in a VM.

The VM is running CentOS 6.6, and it is not the root partition.

Two physical raw disks are currently two physical volumes, that are part of `vg_data` and `lv_data`:

```
/dev/sdb - 10TB
/dev/sdc - 30TB
```

I've created a third that is visible to the OS as:

```
/dev/sdd - 5TB
```

The current 30TB was formated using `xfs`.

```
[root@ds ~]# pvs
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree  
  /dev/sda2  vg_ds   lvm2 a--  63.51g      0 
  /dev/sdb   vg_data lvm2 a--  17.76t      0 
  /dev/sdc   vg_data lvm2 a--   9.78t 551.66g

[root@ds ~]# lvs
  LV       VG       Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move 
  lv_data  vg_data -wi-ao----  27.00t                                                    
  lv_root  vg_ds   -wi-ao----  59.63g                                                    
  lv_swap  vg_ds   -wi-ao----   3.88g 

[root@ds ~]# lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                         11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sda                          8:0    0   64G  0 disk 
├─sda1                       8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                       8:2    0 63.5G  0 part 
  ├─vg_ds-lv_root   (dm-0) 253:0    0 59.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg_ds-lv_swap   (dm-1) 253:1    0  3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                          8:16   0 17.8T  0 disk 
└─vg_data-lv_data   (dm-2) 253:2    0   27T  0 lvm  /mnt/data
sdd                          8:48   0  5.6T  0 disk 
sdc                          8:32   0  9.8T  0 disk 
└─vg_data-lv_data   (dm-2) 253:2    0   27T  0 lvm  /mnt/data
```

How do is add the extra raw disk without harming the current system?
My plan:

1. Use parted to create the physical volume of dev/sdd, with a gpt
   labeled and set the LVM flag to on.
2. Unmount the current `volgrp`

   /dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_data  mounted on /data
3. `vgextend vg_data /dev/sdd`
4. `lvextend -r /dev/vg_data/lv_data /dev/sdd`

Questions:

- Should I run `resize2fs /dev/vg_data/lv_data` instead of using the -r
  option when doing a lvextend?
- How long will this resize take?
- Should I be using xfs_growfs instead? I always thought this was only
  an option if your not using lvm.

Any help, guidance, thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share output of `vgs` and `lvs` before we advice you something. Sure, if /dev/vg_data/lv_data is the LV you want to extend and it's XFS, forget resize2fs, `xfs_growfs` is the correct command then.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Vlastimil. I've edited the post with output from vgs, pvs, and lsblk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first three steps are fine.

I'd only recommend that you send out a notification that the filesystem is going to be unmounted before doing so.

I'm assuming that you already have, but make sure the the fstype is `Linux LVM` for `/dev/sdd`.

Add `/dev/sdd` as a physical volume with the following command:

`pvcreate /dev/sdd`

After that you can run `vgextend /dev/sdd` as you have already planned to do so.

Check your volume group via `vgs` or `vgdisplay` to make sure that the space has been added.

If your `lv` is `/dev/vg_data/lv_data`, then the correct command to add the space from `/dev/sdd` is to first remount your `lv` and then:

```
lvextend -L +5T /dev/vg_data/lv_data
```

After that:

```
xfs_growfs /dev/vg_data/lv_data

lvs
```

or

```
lvdisplay
```

will show that the size has increased for `/dev/vg_data/lv_data`.

If the path to your `lv` is `/dev/mapper/vg_data-lv_data` then substitute that for `/dev/vg_data/lv_data` or else you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the great directions and extra thanks for adding the commands i need @Nasir. Yes this will be done during a maintenance period. Couple of questions... 1. Do i not need to add the drive  `dev/sdd` to the end of the lvextend command? `lvextend -L +5T /dev/vg_data/lv_data /dev/sdd`. 2. How long do you think it will take for the xfs_growfs command to finish resizing the the partition. I'm assuming it's not going to take long as this is one of the many benefits of using this command in comparison to  resize2fs. I'll keep you posted with the results.

Comment: 1) No, you don''t need to add `/dev/sdd` at the end of the command when adding the space to your lv. You just need to add `/dev/sdd` as a physical volume which I'll add to my answer. Make sure that you are using the correct path to your `lv_data` when adding the space to it. 2) I'm assuming that `/dev/sdd` is a locally attached drive so it shouldn't take very long for `xfs_growfs` to add the size to your lv.

Comment: you are the man my friend. Worked like a charm. Only thing I forgot to add was remounting the lv before the xfs_growfs command. Also, it didn't take anymore than about 3 seconds to complete the final resize. Cant thank you enough for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.